# Recent Russian language changes

Tags: история-языка

What are the most significant changes in Russian language in 20th-21st centuries other than orthography rules and lexicon?

Comment: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8248/is-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-used-correctly-here is a nice example

Answer (score 3):

The heavily artificial, but apparently catching, trend towards indeclinable brand names and titles (driven by marketers trying to preserve what they call "brand integrity"). They're using a grammatical loophole of a sort, the implicit qualifier: `работа в "Макдоналдс"` rather than `в "Макдоналдсе"` implying `в ресторанах "Макдоналдс"`, etc. This has led to occasional examples of people not declining anything that goes in quotes, including film and periodical titles. Personally I'm worried/grumpy about the younger generation picking up this lack of declension as intuitively "correct", but it's not such a big deal in the end.

In other "kids these days" developments, the malapropist substitution of `неприкасаемый` for `неприкосновенный` seems to be unstoppable; it's all over the media and no one cares. The latter word may go obsolete, and the former officially take on a meaning (untouchable as in immune or inviolable) antonymous to its original and strictly correct one (untouchable as in pariah).

A minor but very curious example of English borrowings influencing the Russian phonetic inventory, further than the already semi-accepted /w/, is what seems to be a palatalised glottal stop: at least one video game streamer on Twitch rendered "early drops" (a Hearthstone term) as `[ʔʲо]рли-дропы` (there's currently no way to even spell it standardly); this may become bigger in the future.

Answer (score 1):

One trend driven by English influence is shortening some verbs and their derivatives by removing some suffixes in colloquial speech:

```
программировать -> программить 
терраформировать -> терраформить
трансформировать -> трансформить
информировать -> информить
```

etc.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a recent change. Russian language has the tendency to lose parts of long words in informal speech. This way "студенческий билет" becomes "студень" in speech, but is this new?